# Custom Machine Types with Google Genomics Pipelines CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there any way to create a custom instance with the Google Genomics Pipelines CLI (`gcloud alpha genomics pipelines run`)?  I've tried adding `--cpus` and `--memory` but that just seems to size up to the smallest predefined instance meeting those requirements.

I have less experience with the REST api, but I could switch to that, if it supports custom instances.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the custom machine types aren't supported through the CLI and only through the v2alpha1 api. It's also worth noting that even the v2alpha1 api does not support extended memory. *However*, based on the pricing model you end up losing money by running extended memory machines, compared to running a highmem machine with comparable memory.